# Get client domain from request in node.js & express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'd like to get a client's host domain on backend side.
e.g.

- frontend (http://localhost:3000)
- backend (http://localhost:4000)

On frontend side, send api requeset to backend using ajax.

```
$.get('http://localhost:4000/auth');
```

On backend side, I did like this.

```
// routes/auth.js

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.headers.referer);
...
});
...
module.exports = router;
```

this is my `app.js` in backend.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const authRoutes = require('./routes/auth.js');
...
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use('/auth', authRoutes);
...
```

Expected result:

```
localhost:3000
```

Current result:

```
undefined
```

It shows backend url.

When I did console.log(req.headers), it's the following.

- Request from Postman

```
{ 'user-agent': 'PostmanRuntime/7.17.1',
  accept: '*/*',
  'cache-control': 'no-cache',
  'postman-token': '5eb5791e-3a5a-4285-83c9-33320d935a2e',
  host: 'localhost:4000',
  'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
  cookie:
   'connect.sid=s%3A5DIRzqn5HVL3vra410YJ6I56uo9qIj2M.6OWL8rKr1peEMz60sakejaeJJNgv5LQFUKypA6cCXLQ',
  connection: 'keep-alive' }
```

- Request from Frontend

```
{ host: 'localhost:4000',
  accept: '*/*',
  'content-type': 'application/json' }
```

Is there something I did wrong? Please someone help me.

Comment: @Subburaj yes, host is also "localhost:4000"

Comment: I added req.headers

Comment: try : 

**console.log(req.headers.host);**

Answer (score 0):

> The Referer request header contains the address of the previous web page from which a link to the currently requested page was followed.

[docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referer)

Or in other words, click ok a link somewhere in `http://localhost:4000` that *refers* to `http://localhost:5000`, then the `referer` will be set.

Or maybe `referer` is not really what you are looking for. Have a look at [`host`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Host).